# Using crashplan to backup a time machine disk

Tags: time-machine, backup

So, [crashplan themselves say it can't and shouldn't be done](http://support.crashplan.com/doku.php/articles/time_machine), because of hard links and how TM works... But can't it, really?! Isn't there any way around it?

Reason I want to use CrashPlan is because it does [everything else I need - except easy recovery](http://www.messagingnews.com/onmessage/ben-gross/time-machine-vs-crashplan-backups#comment-77), which TimeMachine provides.

<sup>PS: "Nope, it can't be done" and a very detailed answer on why, *or* "do it with `rsync`" or something are both ***ok*** here.</sup>

Comment: Note that the crash-plan issue in the link you provide is only for *local* time-machine backups. It does not apply if the backup is a sparse-bundle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not attempt to prove crashplan wrong. Many bad things can happen.
2. Use the new Time Machine ([since Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#timemachine)) instead.
3. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Backups are important, right? So I'd tend to take Crashplan at their word, rather than try and prove them wrong.

However, if I were going to try and use Crashplan with TimeMachine, I'd look into backing up time machine to a sparse image, and then using crashplan to backup the sparse image. TimeMachine automatically backs up to a sparse image when doing backups to a network location. The sparse image itself is just directory containing basic files, these are used to provide the filesystem features, like hard links, that TimeMachine requires.

Whatever you do, remember to test the backup and restore process before you put any faith in it.

Comment: That sounds like a nice idea. I'll try it soon enough.

Comment: Actually, naaah... I now think the nicest part here is advising against doing it with crashplan or whatever other 3rd part! :-)

Answer (score 1):

For backing up my Time Machine volume, I use [SuperDuper!](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/), which correctly handles hard links on folders. I already saved my Time Machine data using the backup in place of the original Time Machine disk.

With Mountain Lion, I plan to use the [multiple Time Machine disks feature](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/21/#time-machine).

Comment: sounds like it wouldn't do incremental and, thus, making it a bad solution for day to day (unlike crashplan or timemachine).

Comment: @Cawas SuperDuper! indeed has an incremental backup capability - the app refers to it as "Smart Update".

Comment: @DanJ kinda late reply, that makes this kinda valid! Also, mouviciel your answer was definitely more complete than mine... And maybe SuperDuper! even works fine with TM. But now I think it's just not worth the risk. **Just update** should be the focus here.